# Instead executing the calculate function my calculator shows the last value I've put in to calculate

Tags: javascript, html, css, calculator

I'm currently following a how to make a calculator tutorial on yt wher I use html css and js. I've just made the calculate() function, and when I call for it in the equal.addEventListener the both values that I want to calculate show up with the operator, but instead of the values to get calculated and get the result on the screen, it shows me on the result screen only the last value that I've chosen, like 9+3, I press equal and the result that shows on the screen is 3 instead of 12
https://codepen.io/pflaviuss/pen/QWxKOGd

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
    <title>Calculator</title>
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Calculator</h1>
    <div class="calculator">
      <div>
        <div class="first-row">
        <div class="result">
            <div class="previous"></div>
            <div class="current"></div>
        </div>
        <button class="clear btn">C</button>
        </div>
   
      <div class="buttons">
        <button class="number btn">7</button>
        <button class="number btn">8</button>
        <button class="number btn">9</button>
        <button class="operator btn">/</button>
      </div>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button class="number btn">4</button>
        <button class="number btn">5</button>
        <button class="number btn">6</button>
        <button class="operator btn">X</button>
      </div>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button class="number btn">1</button>
        <button class="number btn">2</button>
        <button class="number btn">3</button>
        <button class="operator btn">-</button>
      </div>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button class="decimal btn">.</button>
        <button class="number btn">0</button>
        <button class="equal btn">=</button>
        <button class="operator btn">+</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
let operator = '';
let previousValue = '';
let currentValue = '';

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    //Store all components on html in JS 
    let clear = document.querySelector(".clear.btn");
    let equal = document.querySelector(".equal");
    let decimal = document.querySelector(".decimal");
    
    let numbers = document.querySelectorAll(".number");
    let operators = document.querySelectorAll(".operator");

    let previousScreen = document.querySelector(".previous");
    let currentScreen = document.querySelector(".current");

    numbers.forEach((number) => number.addEventListener("click", function(e){
        handleNumber(e.target.textContent)
        currentScreen.textContent = currentValue;
    }))

    operators.forEach((op) => op.addEventListener("click", function(e){
        handleOperator(e.target.textContent);
        previousScreen.textContent = previousValue + " " + operator;
        currentScreen.textContent = currentValue;
    }))

    clear.addEventListener("click", function(){
        previousValue= "";
        currentValue= "";
        operator="";
        previousScreen.textContent = currentValue;
        currentScreen.textContent = currentValue;
    })

    equal.addEventListener("click", function(){
        calculate();
        previousScreen.textContent= '';
        currentScreen.textConent = previousValue;
    })
})

function handleNumber(num){
    if(currentValue.length <=8){
        currentValue += num;
    }
    
}

function handleOperator(op){
    operator = op;
    previousValue = currentValue;
    currentValue= '';
}

function calculate(){
    previousValue = Number(previousValue);
    currentValue = Number(currentValue);

    if(operator === "+"){    
        previousValue += currentValue;
    } else if(operator === "-"){
        previousValue -= currentValue;
    } else if(operator === "X"){
        previousValue *= currentValue;
    }else{
        previousValue /= currentValue;
    }
    previousValue = roundNumber(previousValue);
    previousValue = previousValue.toString();
    currentValue = previousValue.toString();
}

function roundNumber(num){
    return Math.round(num * 1000) /1000;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug is literally a typo:

The bug is the word `Conent` at the line `39` of `script.js`.

```
line:39: currentScreen.textConent = previousValue;
```

The fix is just replace the word `Conent` with `Content`.

```
line:39: currentScreen.textContent = previousValue;
```

After that you will be able to see the result.

Comment: Yep, took me a while to see the mistaked, someone just recommended me to download Spell Checker on vs code, hope with this extension I'm not gonna put stupid questions like these ones anymore. Thanks for the help

Comment: My pleasure, by the way it is not a stupid question, it happens all the time don't worry :)